# Mongo can't find document while using regex with backslash and & character

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm using java with Mongo to find document in database. I'm using following code:

```
Criteria.where(fieldName).regex("Astronomy \& Astrophysics", "i")
```

This String "Astronomy \& Astrophysics" is changed in query to:

```
Astronomy \\& Astrophysics
```

There are documents in database that have fieldName fields equal to:

```
 Astronomy \& Astrophysics
```

But any document isn't returned

What Java code should I use to make my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you have to escape your `backslash \`

Your new code should now look like this

```
Criteria.where(fieldName).regex("Astronomy \\& Astrophysics", "i")
```

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/11

Answer (score 0):

You can use $regex in mongo java driver in earlier version(before 3.0) as :

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("fildName", new BasicDBObject().append("$regex","Astronomy & Astrophysics"));
List cursor = collection.find(query).toArray();
System.out.println("cursor: " + cursor);
```